# Uploading MP3 file to Firebase Storage ends up being a video/mp3 file

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Im trying to save an audio in the new Firebase Storage option, the audio is set as a .mp3 file and the uploaded to Firebase via this code : `UploadTask uploadAudio = storageRef.putFile(audioUri);` 
The problem is that the audio is stored as a video/mp4 file, and because of that the MediaPlayer does not reproduce it as an audio, how can I fix this?

Comment: You can explicitly [specify metadata when you upload the file to Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#add_file_metadata). If you specify `setContentType("audio/mpeg")` it should map the file to an MP3 correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Moving comment to answer:

You can explicitly [specify metadata when you upload the file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#add_file_metadata) to Firebase. If you specify `setContentType("audio/mpeg")` it should map the file to an MP3 correctly.

Comment: i´ll try that, but why the videos and the pdfs are sent with the correct type?

Comment: Firebase Storage uses the following mechanisms to determine the content type: the content type as determined by the underlying system (Android ContentResolver for instance, iOS uses the MobileCoreServices framework), or the `ContentType` in the Firebase Storage Metadata of an uploaded file. We don't consider the file name extension to be relevant--we don't trust users to provide the correct extension for a given file type. It's likely that even though the file is labeled as an `.mp3`, it's actually a video file without video content.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I´ve tryed your answer and it worked! The only problem is that when I try to reproduce the link it says that it´s damaged, I´ve tryed to play it on the Media Player and also copying the link on the web to double check it, do you know why that might be happening?

Comment: @MikeMcDonald is there a list of the correct syntax for the different content type formats you can add in fb storage. For example how would I add m4a? is it just "audio/m4a" ?

Comment: I just use http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html as a reference

Comment: @MikeMcDonald please help with this firebase storage related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/44080673/6144372

Answer (score 2):

```
 class func uploadAudios(data : Data,completion :  @escaping (_ succus : String )->Void){
    var url = ""
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    // Create file metadata including the content type
    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "audio/mpeg"
    let uploadRef = storage.reference().child("audios/\(UUID().uuidString).mp3")
    uploadRef.putData(data, metadata: metadata) { metadata,
        error in
        if error == nil {
            print("successfully uploaded Audio")
            url = (metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString)!
            print("AhmedRabie \(url)")
            completion(url)
        }
        else {
            print("UploadError \(String(describing: error))")
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: the answer in Swift Language but , still the same steps