# How upload video/mp3 file on firebase android

Tags: video, firebase, android-studio-2.0

I am able to uploading/downloading images from firebase but do not know how upload video or .mp3 file on firebase in android.so suggest me. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Rewriting the example from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files) based on the answer given in [Uploading MP3 file to Firebase Storage ends up being a video/mp3 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296166/uploading-mp3-file-to-firebase-storage-ends-up-being-a-video-mp3-file), it seems that a full working example of an audio upload would look something like this:

```
// File or Blob
 file = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/audio.mp3"));

// Create the file metadata
metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
        .setContentType("audio/mpeg")
        .build();

// Upload file and metadata to the path 'audio/audio.mp3'
uploadTask = storageRef.child("audio/"+file.getLastPathSegment()).putFile(file, metadata);

// Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
        System.out.println("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
    }
}).addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onPaused(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        System.out.println("Upload is paused");
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // Handle successful uploads on complete
        Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();
   }
});
```

Comment: Nice.How can i get all others content type(For Video) ?  Thank in advance.