# how to upload video to Firebase on android?

Tags: android, firebase

I want to build an app that it can upload video from SD card to storage, but I only can upload image. Did anyone do that before or have a better approach.

Answer (score 5):

You can find a pretty good answer/explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146354/how-upload-video-mp3-file-on-firebase-android) (and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296166/uploading-mp3-file-to-firebase-storage-ends-up-being-a-video-mp3-file) may help as well). Note that the answer given in the first link actually sets the content type as `"audio/mpeg"`; if you want to upload a video file, you can refer to [this list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) and change the MIME type accordingly.

Comment: use video/mp4 as MIME type for this

Comment: it really works ,thank you