# How to upload an audio file to firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I want to upload an audio file that saved in my mobile internal memory to firebase storage. Here's my code

```
TextView filePathText;
Button sUrlBtn, upload;
Uri audio_uri = null;

public class AddPostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_post);

        filePathText = findViewById(R.id.filePathText);
        upload = findViewById(R.id.add_upload);
        sUrlBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_filePath);

        sUrlBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("*/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
            }
        });
        ...
        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String fileName = filePathText.getText().toString().trim();
                fileName += "/test.mp3";

                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName));
                uploadData(fileName, uri);
            }
        }
    });

private void uploadData(final String file, final Uri uri) {
    ...
    StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    ref.child("tAudio").child("test_audio.mp3").putFile(uri)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                while (!uriTask.isSuccessful()) ;

                if (uriTask.isSuccessful()) {
                    audio_uri = null;
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d("AddPostActivity", "TEST onFailure()...\nException : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        });
}
...

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 10) {
            audio_uri = data.getData();
            filePathText.setText(audio_uri.getEncodedPath());
        } 
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

What I want to do is...
1. Get the file path from the internal memory audio file by clicking the `sUrlBtn`
2. Uploading that audio file to firebase storage by clicking the `upload`

But when I upload that file, `e.getMessage()` is like this.
**Exception : An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.**
Is there any solution to upload the file from android mobile internal memory to firebase storage??

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41450451/10409567

Comment: This mostly happened if you have not allowed storage permission in Firebase