# Unable to play audio message received from firebase chat in flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented firebase chat module with audio message sending functionality implementing. When I am sending audio message, it is stored properly in firestore DB. But, at receivers end, the audio message is not played.

I have used [bubble normal](https://pub.dev/packages/chat_bubbles) library from pub dev, and implemented BubbleNormalAudio

```
BubbleNormalAudio(
  color: const Color(0xFFE8E8EE),
  duration: duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
  position: position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
  isPlaying: isPlaying,
  isLoading: isLoading,
  isPause: isPause,
  onSeekChanged: _changeSeek,
  onPlayPauseButtonClick: () {
    _playAudio(widget.message);
  },
  tail: false,
),
```

This is the widget in which the audio message is loaded.

This is the function created to play audio:

```
Future<void> _playAudio(String audioUrl) async {
    print("audioUrl--"+ audioUrl);

    if (isPause) {
      await audioPlayer.resume();
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = true;
        isPause = false;
      });
    } else if (isPlaying) {
      await audioPlayer.pause();
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = false;
        isPause = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
      await audioPlayer.play(UrlSource(audioUrl));
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = true;
      });
    }

    audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((Duration d) {
      setState(() {
        duration = d;
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });

    audioPlayer.onPositionChanged.listen((Duration p) {
      setState(() {
// Clamp the position to the duration
        position = Duration(
          seconds: p.inSeconds <= duration.inSeconds
              ? p.inSeconds
              : duration.inSeconds,
        );
      });
    });

    audioPlayer.onPlayerComplete.listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = false;
        duration = const Duration();
        position = const Duration();
      });
    });
  }
```

This is the audio file URL which I have printed in log:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/quad-mobile-app.appspot.com/o/audio%2Frecording.m4a%2FNew_Audio.mp3?alt=media&token=6d41eeff-4bbc-4362-96ce-02d3a6279062
```

Not sure, what is going wrong here.
Swift help needed, please.

Answer (score 0):

Unknown media format: the issue is the package can not recognise the file from firebase as an audio. You could download the file into temp storage when user tries to listen to it and read from there, dispose once you close the chat. if you are open to this approach, I could share an example here.

Alt: look into how you [upload your file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296166/uploading-mp3-file-to-firebase-storage-ends-up-being-a-video-mp3-file?rq=3)